# List of IDs for from_date to end_date (columns)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following table:

| ID | Desc | FromDate | ToDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_01 | A | 08.2017 | 10.2020 |
| ID_02 | B | 02.2019 | 09.2029 |
| ID_03 | C | 02.2014 | 02.2019 |
| ID_04 | D | 04.2010 | 01.2019 |
| ID_05 | D | 01.2019 | 09.2029 |

And i would need the following result in oracle sql (from 01.2019 to 09.2022):

| Date | ID | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01.2019 | ID_01 | A |
| 01.2019 | ID_03 | C |
| 01.2019 | ID_04 | D |
| 02.2019 | ID_01 | A |
| 02.2019 | ID_02 | B |
| 02.2019 | ID_03 | C |
| 02.2019 | ID_05 | D |
| 03.2019 | ID_01 | A |
| 03.2019 | ID_02 | B |
| 03.2019 | ID_05 | D |

So the ID should be in the list, if the Date is between the FromDate and ToDate. If two IDs with the same Desc (like ID_04 and ID_05 for 01.2019) are valid, then the lower ID should be taken.

Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generate a calendar for your date range and then join it to your table and the `GROUP BY` the month and the `desc` (note: `DESC` is a reserved word meaning descending order and should not be used as an identifier):

```
WITH calendar (month) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2019-01-01', LEVEL - 1)
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2019-01-01', LEVEL - 1) <= DATE '2019-09-01'
)
SELECT month,
       MIN(id) AS id,
       "DESC"
FROM   calendar c
       INNER JOIN table_name t
       ON (c.month BETWEEN t.fromdate and t.todate)
GROUP BY month, "DESC"
ORDER BY month, id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, "DESC", FromDate, ToDate) AS
  SELECT 'ID_01', 'A', DATE '2017-08-01', DATE '2020-10-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID_02', 'B', DATE '2019-02-01', DATE '2029-09-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID_03', 'C', DATE '2014-02-01', DATE '2019-02-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID_04', 'D', DATE '2010-04-01', DATE '2019-01-01' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID_05', 'D', DATE '2019-01-01', DATE '2019-09-01' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| MONTH | ID | DESC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | ID_01 | A |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | ID_03 | C |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | ID_04 | D |
| 2019-02-01 00:00:00 | ID_01 | A |
| 2019-02-01 00:00:00 | ID_02 | B |
| 2019-02-01 00:00:00 | ID_03 | C |
| 2019-02-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-03-01 00:00:00 | ID_01 | A |
| 2019-03-01 00:00:00 | ID_02 | B |
| 2019-03-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-04-01 00:00:00 | ID_01 | A |
| 2019-04-01 00:00:00 | ID_02 | B |
| 2019-04-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-05-01 00:00:00 | ID_01 | A |
| 2019-05-01 00:00:00 | ID_02 | B |
| 2019-05-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-06-01 00:00:00 | ID_01 | A |
| 2019-06-01 00:00:00 | ID_02 | B |
| 2019-06-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-07-01 00:00:00 | ID_01 | A |
| 2019-07-01 00:00:00 | ID_02 | B |
| 2019-07-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | ID_01 | A |
| 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | ID_02 | B |
| 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-09-01 00:00:00 | ID_01 | A |
| 2019-09-01 00:00:00 | ID_02 | B |
| 2019-09-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zz66jCXM)