# List of IDs for from_date to end_date (other columns differ)

Tags: sql, oracle

Yesterday I posted a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73645599/list-of-ids-for-from-date-to-end-date-columns/73646486?answertab=createdasc#tab-top) regarding a problem I had in oracle sql.
But I still have one problem, which i forgot in my first question. My table also includes other columns for rows with the same DESC. Like this:

| ID | Desc | FromDate | ToDate | Color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID_01 | A | 08.2017 | 10.2020 | Red |
| ID_02 | B | 02.2019 | 09.2029 | Blue |
| ID_03 | C | 02.2014 | 02.2019 | Black |
| ID_04 | D | 04.2010 | 01.2019 | Yellow |
| ID_05 | D | 01.2019 | 09.2029 | Green |

This is the reason why I still get both IDs (4 and 5) with the posted sql. How can I prevent this in the best way?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

```
select "Date"
       ,ID
       ,"Desc"
from        (
            select "Date"
                   ,ID
                   ,"Desc"
                   ,row_number() over(partition by "Desc" order by ID) as rn
            from t 
            unpivot
           ("Date" for FDTD in ("FromDate","ToDate")) 
            where "Date" between date '2019-01-01' and date '2022-09-01'
           ) t
where rn = 1
```

| Date | ID | Desc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-OCT-20 | ID_01 | A |
| 01-FEB-19 | ID_02 | B |
| 01-FEB-19 | ID_03 | C |
| 01-JAN-19 | ID_04 | D |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/dM9BT4Du)

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (ID, "DESC", FromDate, ToDate, Colour) AS
  --SELECT 'ID_01', 'A', DATE '2017-08-01', DATE '2020-10-01', 'Red' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  --SELECT 'ID_02', 'B', DATE '2019-02-01', DATE '2029-09-01', 'Blue' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  --SELECT 'ID_03', 'C', DATE '2014-02-01', DATE '2019-02-01', 'Black' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID_04', 'D', DATE '2010-04-01', DATE '2019-01-01', 'Yellow' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 'ID_05', 'D', DATE '2019-01-01', DATE '2019-09-01', 'Green' FROM DUAL;
```

*(and just focusing on the `D` values for `DESC`)*

Then the accepted answer to the linked question:

```sql
WITH calendar (month) AS (
  SELECT ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2019-01-01', LEVEL - 1)
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY ADD_MONTHS(DATE '2019-01-01', LEVEL - 1) <= DATE '2019-09-01'
)
SELECT month,
       MIN(id) AS id,
       "DESC"
FROM   calendar c
       INNER JOIN table_name t
       ON (c.month BETWEEN t.fromdate and t.todate)
GROUP BY month, "DESC"
ORDER BY month, id;
```

Only outputs a single `DESC` values for each day and there is only the corresponding minimum `ID`:

| MONTH | ID | DESC |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2019-01-01 00:00:00 | ID_04 | D |
| 2019-02-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-03-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-04-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-05-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-06-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-07-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-08-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |
| 2019-09-01 00:00:00 | ID_05 | D |

The reason that you get `ID_04` for `2019-01-01` and then `ID_05` for the rest of the days is that `ID_04` has a `toDate` value of `2019-01-01` so it cannot be included in the range from `2019-02-01` through to `2019-09-01` as those months are outside the upper bound of its range. Instead, you get `ID_05` for those months because they are within its range.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NjZk0SET)